# How to use frida to hook intent.getData()?

Tags: frida

The source code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

How to print the `data` or hook the `getData()` function?

My frida js code is as follows:

```
var intent = Java.use("android.content.Intent");
intent.getData.implementation=function()
{
    console.log("intent");
    return this.getData();
}
```

But it didn't work. Who can help me?

Comment: Are you sure you hooked the right app? Intents are often used for inter-process communication, therefore if two apps are involved you have to hook the receiver of the Intent not the sender.

Comment: Yes,I hooked the app who is the Intent receiver, but there is no error and can't works.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the relevant Android app code as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just directly hook getData() function

Steps:

1. You need to hook getIntent() Method.
2. You need to hook getData() which is sub method.
3. Store getData()'s return value in same variable.
4. Print the value.

Frida Code:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    var act = Java.use("android.app.Activity");
    act.getIntent.implementation = function() {

        var intent = this.getIntent()

        var data = intent.getData();
        console.log(data);

        return intent;
    };

})
```

Output:

```
❯ frida -U -l value.js -f com.frida.intentpassing
     ____
    / _  |   Frida 15.1.28 - A world-class dynamic instrumentation toolkit
   | (_| |
    > _  |   Commands:
   /_/ |_|       help      -> Displays the help system
   . . . .       object?   -> Display information about 'object'
   . . . .       exit/quit -> Exit
   . . . .
   . . . .   More info at https://frida.re/docs/home/
   . . . .
   . . . .   Connected to Google Pixel (id=192.168.56.101:5555)
Spawned `com.frida.intentpassing`. Use %resume to let the main thread start executing!
[Google Pixel::com.frida.intentpassing ]-> %resume
[Google Pixel::com.frida.intentpassing ]-> null
```

As there is no any data that's why it's showing `Null`